# How to do Ember.SimpleAuth.setup using ember-simple-auth via AMD

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Before using ember-cli-simple-auth I had this initializer:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    container.register('authenticator:api', Oauth2Authenticator);

    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application, {
      authorizerFactory: 'ember-simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
      routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard',
      routeAfterInvalidation: 'login',
      storeFactory: 'ember-simple-auth-session-store:local-storage'
    });
  }
});
```

How to do that now, when using imports, I've managed to get to the point:

```
import Oauth2Authenticator from '../services/authenticator';

export default {
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    container.register('authenticator:api', Oauth2Authenticator);

    // THIS PART IS NOT CLEAR, HOW TO SETUP IN AMD?
    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application, {
      authorizerFactory: 'ember-simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
      routeAfterAuthentication: 'dashboard',
      routeAfterInvalidation: 'login',
      storeFactory: 'ember-simple-auth-session-store:local-storage'
    });
    // END OF CONFUSING PART
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not call `SimpleAuth.setup` anymore as it's private API now. If you're using Ember CLI simply install the Ember CLI addon: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth. If you're using EAK (in which case you should migrate to Ember CLI anyway), make sure you require the Ember Simple Auth autoloader:

`require('simple-auth/ember');`

Also checkout the installation instructions in the README: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#installation

In both cases you don't have to call `SimpleAuth.setup`. If you want to register your custom authenticator, simply add an initializer that runs before the 'simple-auth' initializer:

```
import Oauth2Authenticator from '../services/authenticator';

export default {
  name: 'authentication',
  before: 'simple-auth',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    container.register('authenticator:api', Oauth2Authenticator);
  }
};
```

Configuration is now done via the global `ENV` object - see API docs here: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Configuration